# How was `val hash : 'a -> int` was implemented in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

In OCaml, `Hashtbl` can `hash` any thing to an int

> Hashtbl.hash x associates a nonnegative integer to any value of any type. It is guaranteed that if x = y or Pervasives.compare x y = 0, then hash x = hash y. Moreover, hash always terminates, even on cyclic structures.

I mean, in `Java`, we have `hashCode()` for every object which returns an integer and Java's Hashtable can hash that integer.

But how did OCaml achieve that to hash anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not tricky. `Hashtbl.hash` just traverses data in a manner similar to the way the garbage collector does it. It travels a fixed distance into the linked structure, which avoids failing when there are cycles. It doesn't know anything about the high-level types of what it encounters, it just hashes the primitive values it reaches.

You can see the code in byterun/hash.c in the OCaml source distribution.

**Update**

It occurs to me you might have been asking how `Hashtbl.hash` was implemented *in OCaml*. The answer is that it can't be implemented in OCaml (without cheating) because it violates parametricity. The only possible pure functions of type `'a -> int` are ones that return a constant value. The intuition is that such a function can't use any information about its argument because it is defined for all possible types.

`Hashtbl.hash` is one of a few OCaml functions that violate parametricity. They exist in OCaml because they're extremely handy. Another notorious one is the polymorphic comparison `compare` (and the associated `=` operator).

Comment: thanks, I just add the link to the hash.c here: https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-ocaml/blob/master/byterun/hash.c

Comment: Jeffrey, could you please tell me if we are going to map an integer to  0 to M-1, why do we normally choose M as Prime or Power of 2?

Comment: Prime: spreads the values out better (everything is relatively prime to it). Power of 2: easy to calculate by masking.

Comment: sorry jeffrey, I am not sure I understand your update. What means parametricity?

Comment: In a language with parametric polymorphism (an FP language), parametricity refers to the principle that you can deduce properties of a function just from the type. At least that's what I mean here! As I said, the intuition is that a function can't "look inside" its polymorphic parameters because it has no idea what they are.

Comment: The OCaml runtime memory layout carries some limited amount of type information. It distinguishes values between integers (n is represented as 2n+1, thus a odd number) and pointers (even numbers) to blocks. Blocks are themselves made of values (except for float arrays and certain special blocks), enabling recursive descent.

Comment: Right, this is exactly how the polymorphic hash and equality functions work. But in so doing they violate the principle of parametricity. It wouldn't be possible to access this type info from OCaml itself (without cheating).