# How to write the function `compare : 'a -> 'a -> int` in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Well, the title of this question explains itself.

In `Pervasives`, `compare` function is external.

What if I am asked to implement such a function in OCaml? Is that possible?

Comment: Only using `Obj.magic`.

Comment: @nlucaroni what do you mean? `Obj.magic` is also external

Comment: In my opinion, the best answer is that it's not possible. (Note: Obj.magic isn't really a function; it generates no code. So it's hard to claim that it's external. But Obj.magic isn't part of OCaml, or this is my claim anyway.)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I guess you can transform your comment to answer. Also I read the https://github.com/MassD/ocaml/blob/master/stdlib/obj.ml, it seems it is external, no?

Comment: Although I mentioned it, I agree with JeffreyScofield. `Obj.magic` is not an appropriate solution. @JacksonTale, the `Obj` module is part of the stdlib, but it's bad practice to use.

Comment: We discussed these issues before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576260/how-was-val-hash-a-int-was-implemented-in-ocaml/15576666#15576666. Obj.magic uses compiler "magic" to treat a value one type as though it was a different type. It's not really a function, and I would say it's not external.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield lol I did ask that question and I totally forgot, how could you still remember?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible.

We cannot implement in OCaml functions that are both polymorphic and inspect the data corresponding to the type parameter. The `Obj` module can make this possible but it is "not part of the OCaml language" (X. Leroy).

`Pervasives.compare` is implemented in C and could be implemented similarly using the `Obj` module. It relies on the runtime representation of OCaml values, and as a consequence the order cannot be customized on a per-type basis without extra tagging.